Market demands more people – yet individual companies do not welcome newcomers. How can it be resolved?
The job market, as a whole, demands more developers (here's the US forecast).
However, individual companies typically do not welcome new people in the field (I could find some reference, but you can just type "software developer" on a web site like Indeed and see how many of them are entry-level).
I figure it's some game theory thing.
I also suspect it doesn't affect IT jobs exclusively. This question is not about any particular job field or any particular country.
To me, the problem seems to be caused mainly by these two circumstances:

Companies are not willing to invest their time and money in entry-level candidates. They want someone else to do that investment (parents, government, other companies) and then, hopefully, reap the benefits by employing such individuals (the "free rider" problem).

Companies lack the ability to effectively assess applicants' skills. At the end of the day, it's the workers' skills that add value, not their CVs or diplomas. The latter two are used as proxies to make an assessment of applicants' qualifications, but, in my view, both proved to be inaccurate and unreliable. It created unnecessary bottlenecks that hurt the workers, the companies, and the job market as a whole (though, full disclosure, I'm biased as, while being currently employed, I am also involved in a challenging job search at this time).


What are some of the solutions suggested by scholars or, perhaps, even successfully implemented in other countries?
For example, should governments, besides education, provide some "primary employment" for people entering the workforce to improve their employability and make the job market healthier by streamlining the inflow of new professionals?

Quite often, companies put completely unrealistic requirements in their job ads, like asking 10 years experience in a technology existing only for 5 years.

The folks who write the want ads are not always the ones who are working in the technology. If you think you can convince them that you are a good candidate, submit an application even if you aren't an exact match. The worst that happens is that you have wasted a bit of your time, and theirs.

"What are some of the solutions suggested by scholars to this societal issue" is not really a workplace question, within the scope that we have defined here. "How can I get a job without a degree" would be, but I believe it has already been answered.

"on a web site like Indeed" - That is because most of those jobs on Indeed do not actually exist.

I must say that I disagree with your assertion.  My own company welcomes new developers as well as my previous two.  The young man sitting next to me, this was his first job and his education is not in software development.
The same holds true for my mentee and a few of the people I was hired with.
Now there is a lot of negative press about the current batch of young people and how awful they are at being responsible.  (This is a popular subject for people of my age, and has always been the case.)
However the young people I work with are amazing.  I find them smart, willing to learn, hard working and capable.  My mentee graduated college in July, just joined a new team more inline with his goals, is running a half ironman in a few weeks, and will be starting his masters shortly afterward.
What company would not want a "kid" like that?
So I disagree with your assertion and you did nothing to prove it.
Can you recognize that this is a meaningless statement?

I figure it's some game theory thing.


"My first question would be do you have a 4 year degree in an engineering discipline? Without one you are limiting your job prospects." I'd be happy to, but not everyone can afford it. Your statement that it's me who are limiting my job prospects because of that, is, imo, elitist and wrong

"My own company welcomes new developers as well as my previous two." While your personal experience may be different, my question, with respect, is not about your company or your experience

@SergeyZolotarev  I am sorry you do not like my answer, but you did nothing to prove your assertion which I disagree with.  In response I have given counter examples.  Its tough completing your education but well worth it.

I didn't say, "it's tough so I don't do it". I don't mind doing tough things. I said I cannot afford it. It's different

"you did nothing to prove your assertion" I did. The number of entry-level positions companies publish do not agree well with the demand figures I cited

@SergeyZolotarev the fact that you can't afford to get a degree in the field you're interested in does not mean that the requirement for such a degree should be ignored. If I desperately want to be an aeronautical engineer but can't afford to get the necessary degree, should Boeing hire me anyway and let me design aircraft? Clearly not (although given recent circumstances one might wonder ...), so why should your situation be different? You'd like to argue that such a degree is not necessary for you ro perform the job - but you're arguing from a position of Dunning-Kruger ignorance - ...

... you don't (yet) know everything that you don't know, so you don't (yet) have the knowledge or skills to be able to make the determination whether or not such a degree really is necessary to be ale to perform the job you want. The company with the position needing to be filled is usually in a far better position to make that decision than you are.

Note that part of the purpose of education is specifically as a substitute for experience, both giving you the necessary basic skills and certifying that you have them. That is why companies prefer beginners who have degrees over those who don't. Believe me, the computer industry would love to be able to count on self-trained high school graduates that they could pay less; they have been talking about trying to move in that direction, which is one reason you see some of them experimenting with free online courses. If you can't afford education, work some other job and save until you can.

@brhans sure it's not necessary. Don't listen to me, listen to more experienced developers, like Bob Martin. If your Boeing analogy held any water, it would be a legal requirement to have such a degree (similar to how it's required to have a degree to become a surgeon). If you believe any existing country practices that, feel free to provide such an example

@SergeyZolotarev I think you'll find that in regulated industries it is a legal requirement for companies to hire suitably educated & qualified candidates. But just because a particular industry is not regulated doesn't mean that companies operating in that industry are unable to best gauge for themselves what requirements they'd have for suitable employees.

I'm not saying that self-taught developers are all useless - I'm largely self-taught as my primary qualification is in Electrical Engineering, while the job I practice is Firmware/Software development, but the main reason I'm able to do this job is due to years of experience in the field (which I gained while self-employed). A software education could have jump-started the process (if I'd known back then that this is where I'd end up).

@brhans also, important note. In regulated industries, education is largely about learning and applying professional standards. Software engineering doesn't really have standards. Bob Martin and some others try to change that (clean code, SOLID, TDD, CI/CD etc.), but Computer Science degrees that employers expect have almost nothing to do with those standards. While it may help learn a few things, that knowledge's practical applicability in a real production application is limited (again, ask more seasoned devs, if you will)

@SergeyZolotarev - Many engineering jobs (civil engineering) require not only a college degree but certification from the state. As a computer engineer I could have received one of those state board certifications if I wanted because they their topic isn't specific to those fields but are generalized to engineering. Boeing will hire whom they believe can do the job and allow them to finish a project. They will rely a small amount of senior and likely certified engineers to fact check the work of more junior employees. Boeing failures has less to do with engineers and more to do with their PMs.


The job market, as a whole, demands more developers

And you know how the market expresses demand, don't you? With higher wages, drawing more candidates in until an equilibrium is reached.
The predominant environment is that boss mouthpieces and lobbyists demand cheaper developers, not that markets demand more developers.

There have always been complaints that you can't get a job because you don't have experience, and the only way to get experience is to get a job.
A different issue might be happening. Once a person is unemployed, they find it hard to get a job. They are viewed as risky hires because if the new employer offers them a job beneath their skill level, they will jump to a better job at the first chance.
The problem is that if you never hire unemployed people, then the holes never get filled, the holes just move around. A have seen this happen to multiple family members.
Most of the new graduates are technically unemployed or under-employed while in school.  That makes some hiring managers nervous. That means they would rather make an offer to somebody already in their first position, not somebody looking for their first position.

I don't know any hiring manager that views recent college graduates unfavorably because they didn't have a job during college.

Given the high number of unemployed people with relevant experience, many of them willing to work under their seniority level because they're bored out of their skull being unemployed (and even a junior or medior level salary is better than unemployment benefits or social security) it's not unusual for new starters in the job market to be passed over.
This phenomenon has been going on (in waves each time the economy has even a slight upswing) for decades, probably centuries. E.g. when I graduated with a college degree in the mid 1990s I found it impossible to find a job in my field, despite having good grades. Lots of more experienced people had lost their jobs in the field over the preceding year or two and were flooding the job market, making for companies having a choice of experienced workers willing to work for not much more money than the junior salary I'd get as a fresh graduate. I eventually found work in an entirely different field (software engineering) where there WAS a serious lack of people at all levels and they were happy to hire me despite no experience but a good attitude and willingness to learn.

Thank you for your answer. However, I cannot confirm it actually answers the question

@SergeyZolotarev basically, life sucks

"Life is a bitch. But the puppies are cute."

If we assume the Bureau of Labor Statistics is correctly predicting the future, there will be a 17% increase in programmer jobs between 2023 and 2033.  That's above average but it is not a particularly large annualized rate of change-- the US economy just needs to replace whatever developers are retiring plus about 1% to hit that.  A lot more people are graduating with software development resumes today than were graduating 40 years ago (though lots of retiring software developers graduated with degrees in something else) so it is entirely possible that the number of software development jobs is increasing just not as quickly as the number of new software engineering graduates is.
If we assume that developers have 40 year careers and that "entry-level" is someone with 0-2 years of experience, you'd naively expect that about 5% of job postings (2/40) are for entry-level roles while 95% are for more senior positions.
But that probably overstates things.  Companies that are hiring entry-level developers are generally not posting positions on Indeed, they've got a whole campus recruiting arm that is recruiting people from colleges, boot camps, etc.  Job boards work to match widely distributed employees with widely distributed employers.  But entry-level developers aren't generally widely distributed-- they're graduating school at very predictable times a few times a year-- so it's easier for companies to go there to recruit.
But that also doesn't take into account that it takes a lot longer to hire a senior role than a junior role.  If you're just counting open job posts, there is going to be a significant skew towards experienced roles because they're open longer.  If I post an open job for a Java developer with 0 experience, I'll have 100 resumes from qualified applicants by lunch.  If I post an open job for a Java developer with 15 years of experience that has business knowledge of the automotive manufacturing sector, several frameworks, etc., it may take several weeks to get 10 resumes from people that meet the qualifications well enough to be worth interviewing.  If the experienced position stays open 10 times longer, that is going to skew the results of looking at job boards.
